# Try, catch and Exception handling

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

`Test` class:

```
package learning;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    static Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        try {
            t.run(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                t.run(user.nextInt());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                try {
                    t.run(user.nextInt());
                } catch (Exception dd) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Test2` class:

```
package learning;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test2 extends Test {
    public int x = 0;

    public void run(int a) throws Exception, IOException {
        do {
            if (a > 1)
                System.out.println(a);
            x = x + 1;
            if (a < 1) {
                System.out.println("you're wrong");
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } while (x==0);
    }
}
```

It will stop running if `a > 0`, but when I answer with a string it will also stop running. How do I get the program to ask again and if I enter 2 times a number below 1 it will also stop running how do I make it endless?

Comment: Can you please reformat your code?

Comment: Hopefully one day you'll learn that throwing exceptions is kind of not a good thing to do in many cases, especially throwing exceptions with no message. And that a zillion `try-catch` blocks is hideous.

Comment: no idea why you cal run(0) and the run(nextInt()). Maybe you can explain yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to make anything endless is to throw a while(true) loop on it. Better programming practices may include properly disposing by doing while(started) and setting started to false.

In your case I am not sure what you intention is... so the following should work. Also get rid of that do while loop. To be honest this code can totally be written cleaner but you can just play around for now.

```
public class Test {
static Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test2 t = new Test2();
    while(true) {
        try {
            t.run(user.nextInt());
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```